# How to automatically answer no to attempt to continue script with unzip command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, unzip

I have a bash script, which is scheduled and has to be executed without any user interaction after it starts.
My bash script has an unzip command inside that looks like this:

```
yes n | unzip -o ${filename}
```

I use `yes` command to answer to the following question prompted to the user:

```
write error (disk full?).  Continue? (y/n/^C)
```

The problem is: user can't answer to this question because the script is scheduled to run on its own without user interaction.
That's the reason i use `yes`, but I will never be sure that the answer that i automatically provide (n in this case) will be provided to the question I mentioned above. I also used the option `-o` to avoid the command `yes` answering to the 
`replace foo? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: y` question

I would like a suggestion to a safer/better way to avoid any user interaction on this script. I need the unzip command to overwrite existing files and answering 'n' to `Continue? (y/n/^C)`

Comment: `expect` might help you.

Comment: Wouldn't redirecting stdin from /dev/null work here?

Comment: Can't use `expect` since my enviroenment does not support it.

Comment: do a preliminary step to flag as error if filesystem is getting too full then exit this process as it will likely fail anyhow  ... then perform the unzip step so its output dir or file is in some alternative location ... then do a simple shell confirmation the unzip file or dir exists and if good then mv the freshly unzipped into actual live location ... then have a step to confirm existence of new file